# HQL query or criteria to get average no. of transactions performed

Tags: hibernate, aggregate-functions

I am trying to get a HQL query or criteria to get the average no. of transactions performed on a particular date, given a date range and resource.

the table user_transactions has following fields (and corresponding domain class UserTransaction)
transaction_id, user_id, resource, transdate.

right now I am doing:

```
UserTransaction.createCriteria().list {   
                between('transdate', fromDate, toDate)
                projections {  
                  avg('transaction_id')  
                  groupProperty('graresource')
                  groupProperty('transdate')
                 }
               }
```

Is the above approach right? if not how should the query be so that I get the average number of transaction performed on a date for a resource by all users?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Right now I am getting too many results with this Query.

Comment: Is transdate a date or a timestamp?  What is the SQL generated and executed here?  "getting too many results" would indicate to me an issue with the restrictions (where clause); is that what you mean?  You get back rows outside the date range?

Comment: transdate is a date field, I have activiy for all dates in a range of a month for example, and have 4 resources, then I need to have aveg no. of transaction on each day for each resource - so total of 120 arnd max records, but I am getting like in thousands, now that I think about it, its getting grouped with date and time together, how can I specify not to include time in grouping in hibernate criteria, like a format specifier?

Comment: Its kind of weird in Oracle sql developer, transdate is a date field with no time to it. I changed the field to timestamp and now I see there is a valid, non zero time  for each date value, like it always existed and  was just hiding it. Not sure what this means but I think the grouping is taking the time into consideration since the average value of the transaction_id is always 1.

Comment: Yep, the datatype DATE in Oracle is both date+time http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#i1847